# How to access scope from async callback

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

It must seems really simple but I have no idea how to access $scope from an async function.
With the following I won't udpate $scope.result until I reload the tab manually.

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, Camera) {
    $scope.getBarcode = function () {
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
            $scope.result = result.text;
        }, function (error) {
            //alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        });
    };
}
```

Could you let me know how to proceed ?

Thanks !

Comment: You are able to access the scope, you just need to add `$scope.$apply()` to force a digest cycle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trigger digest cycle manually in this case, since `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan` is not Angular method so framework has no idea that this code should update bindings. In this case you need to kick of digest yourself with `$scope.$apply()`:

```
$scope.getBarcode = function () {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
        $scope.result = result.text;
        $scope.$apply();
    }, function (error) {
        //alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in calls to `$scope.apply` because the cordova `scan` function is not integrated with angular, so angular won't know it needs to re-digest the scope and update the page.

```
function (result) {
  $scope.apply(function () {
    $scope.result = result.text;
  }); 
}
```